# Send message to user when he is online in Pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I am using Pyrogram to make userbot. I need to check if user is online and if he is online I will send him a message. I couldn't understand documentation.

```
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client(
    "my_account",
    api_id= 111111111,
    api_hash='bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
)
chat_id = 777777777
with app:
    peer = app.resolve_peer(chat_id)
    if(is_user_online(chat_id)):
        app.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='Hello!')
```

I tried to use `pyrogram.types.User`, but I didn't understand what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a user is online, you could use the `get_users()` method of the Client class that checks the status field of the returned User object.

```
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client(
    "my_account",
    api_id= 111111111,
    api_hash='bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
)

chat_id = 777777777

with app:
    user = app.get_users(chat_id)
    if str(user.status) == "UserStatus.ONLINE"
        app.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Hello!")
```

The status field of the User object tells you when the user was online for the last time.

Comment: It says 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\UserBot\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    if user.status.online:
AttributeError: 'UserStatus' object has no attribute 'online'

Comment: I've updated my code, please try giving it another look

Comment: after this code it is working:
if str(user.status) == "UserStatus.ONLINE":

Comment: Ah okay great, I'll update my code so other people could also use it